# How to search a folder with its subfolders and save the results to an array VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to execute a search on a folder and get an array of every result back. I found this code but it doesn't go into subfolders:

```
        Dim Results As New List(Of String)
    For Each strFileName As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("pathToSearch")
        If strFileName.Contains("searchTerm") Then
            Results.Add(strFileName)
        End If
    Next
```

How can I do exactly this, but also look into the subfolders?

I'm not very knowledgeable about the search options in VB.NET yet, so I apologize in advance if this seems stupid. I have tried searching online but haven't found anything. I can't have a single string, it needs to be an array (this needs to be interpreted by the machine later in the program)

Thanks for any help

Comment: You say "array" but have a `List`, FYI these are not the same thing (but you *are* using the more appropriate `List` in this case).

Comment: OK, but I am using the list as an array: Results(entryno.) Thanks for claraification.

Comment: You can't `Add` on an array, so *no*, you are not using it as an array even thought both and `Array` and a `List` can be accessed by index. Also, did you try searching here or on the internet? I can see pleny of potential answers for you.

Answer (score 1):

No recursion required. There is already an overload for this. You just need to call it with appropriate search option.

e.g. To list all txt files in the directory as well as the subdirectories you can do:

```
Dim foundFiles() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("path/to/dir", "*.txt", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: Nice, I never knew about this overload.  Here we were trying to re-invent the wheel!

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the subfolders you might try some recursive function

Comment: I tried something like this where I would get all directories and search all directories, and add to the big list. Problem with this is that the folder amount increases exponentially, so I find myself manually searching hundreds of folders.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a file system search API with which I'm unfamiliar, this is going to involve a recursive method to perform the searching into sub-directories.

Helpfully, Microsoft even [has a complete example of something very similar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303974) available.  In VB it might look something like this (my VB is *very* rusty and this is free-hand code, by the way...):

```
Function FindFiles(ByVal dir As String, ByVal searchTerm As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim Results As New List(Of String)

    ' search files in this directory
    For Each strFileName As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir)
        If strFileName.Contains(searchTerm) Then
            Results.Add(strFileName)
        End If
    Next

    ' recurse into child directories
    For Each strDirectoryName As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
        Results = Results.AddRange(FindFiles(strDirectoryName, searchTerm)
    Next

    Return Results
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it might work. However are you sure you meant to type Concat, it says _'Concat' is not a member'List(Of String)'._. It offers Count, Contains, CopyTo. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: @GabeNewell: You're right, I had my environments mixed up.  (Been doing a lot more JavaScript development today.)  I believe it should be `.AddRange()` instead.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make a recursive function that keeps calling itself until all subdirectories are checked:

```
Private Function GetAllFileNamesFromDirectory(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal strSearchTerm As String) As List(Of String)

    Dim lstFileNames As New List(Of String)

    Dim lstSubDirectories As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetDirectories(strPath).ToList()

    Dim lstFilesToAdd As List(Of String) = IO.Directory.GetFiles(strPath).ToList()

    For Each strFileToAdd As String In lstFilesToAdd

        If strFileToAdd.Contains(strSearchTerm) Then

            'Additional logic would be required to filter out the directory name.
            lstFileNames.Add(strFileToAdd)

        End If

    Next

    If lstSubDirectories.Count > 0 Then

        lstSubDirectories.ForEach(Sub(strDirectoryPath As String)

                                      Dim lstSubDirectoryFilesToAdd As List(Of String) = GetAllFileNamesFromDirectory(strDirectoryPath, strSearchTerm)

                                      If lstSubDirectoryFilesToAdd.Count > 0 Then

                                          lstFileNames.AddRange(lstSubDirectoryFilesToAdd)

                                      End If

                                  End Sub)

    End If

    Return lstFileNames

End Function
```